# Solving a simple ${\cal O}(N\log N)$ recursive equation.

Tags: asymptotics, recursive-algorithms

A recursive divide and conquer algorithm runs for input size $N$ in $T(N)$ time where

$$
\begin{align}
        T(1)&={\cal O}(1) \\
        T(N)&={\cal O}(1)+2T(N/2)+{\cal O}(N) \\
        \end{align}
$$

This should be $T(N)={\cal O}(N\log N)$. I tried the following to solve it:

$$
\begin{align}
T(N)&={\cal O}(1)+2T(\frac N2)+{\cal O}(N) \\
&={\cal O}(1)+2\big( {\cal O}(1)+2T(\frac N4)+{\cal O}(N/2)\big) +{\cal O}(N) \\
&={\cal O}(1)+2\Big( {\cal O}(1)+2\big({\cal O}(1)+2T(\frac N8)+{\cal O}(N/4)\big)+{\cal O}(N/2)\Big) +{\cal O}(N) \\
&=(4+2+1){\cal O}(1)+8T(\frac N8)+4{\cal O}(\frac N4)+2{\cal O}(\frac N2)+{\cal O}(N) \\
\text {after }i \text{ times} \\
&= (2^i-1){\cal O}(1)+2^iT(\frac N{2^i})+2^{i-1}{\cal O}(\frac N{2^{i-1}})+2^{i-2}{\cal O}(\frac N{2^{i-2}})+\ldots+2{\cal O}(\frac N2)+{\cal O}(N) \\
\text{use }i=\log_2N \\
&=(N-1){\cal O}(1)+N{\cal O}(1)+\frac N2{\cal O}(2)+\frac N4{\cal O}(4)+\ldots+2{\cal O}(\frac N2)+{\cal O}(N)
\end{align}
$$

Now the first two summands are obviously ${\cal O}(N)$, but I’m at loss for the remaining summands.

How do I lead the remaining summands into ${\cal O}(N \log N)$? And did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}(N)+\mathcal{O}(1)=\mathcal{O}(N)$

Comment: $\frac{n}{2} O(2n) \leq c_1 \frac{n}{2} 2n=c_1 n^2 = O(n^2)$ so your expression can't be $O(n \log n)$

Answer (score 1):

Considering the Master Theorem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem, which is used specifically for determining the run-times of divide and conquer algorithms, first note that as 
$$T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n), \qquad a \geq 1, b > 1$$
and your recurrence relation is
$$T(n)={\cal O}(1)+2T(n/2)+{\cal O}(n) = 2T(n/2)+{\cal O}(n),$$
it follows that $a = 2,b=2,c=1$ and so $c = 1 = \log_2 2$. Taking $k = 0$, we are in **Case 2** shown in the wikipedia entry I linked earlier. Hence 
$$T(n) = {\cal O}(n^c \log^{k+1}n) = {\cal O}(n\log n).$$

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're being too loose. Because the number of terms in the sum (where I've fixed the errors in your substitution)

$$\frac{N}{1} \mathcal{O}(1) + \frac{N}{2} \mathcal{O}(2) + \frac{N}{4} \mathcal{O}(4) + \cdots + 1 \mathcal{O}(N) $$

is not constant but depends on $N$, the sum could turn out to be anything at all if the hidden constants behave sufficiently pathologically.

You really should translate the problem out of big-oh notation to do the analysis, and then back into big-oh notation at the end.

Comment: This sum looks good; I remember that my algorithms & data structures professor used a very special trick to prove that this sum does indeed equal ${\cal O}(N\log N)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it now. If we look at
$$
\frac N1{\cal O}(1)+\frac N2{\cal O}(2)+\frac N4{\cal O}(4)+\ldots+4{\cal O}(\frac N4)+2{\cal O}(\frac N2)+1{\cal O}(N)
$$
we can make certain that each summand is ${\cal O}(N)$. That yields
$$
{\cal O}(N)+{\cal O}(N)+\ldots+{\cal O}(N)+{\cal O}(N)
$$
Now the question remains how many summands there are.

Assume $N$ is a power of $2$. Then there exist $\log_2 N$ summands.

That’s $\log_2 N*{\cal O}(N)={\cal O}(N\log N)$.

Comment: But as I mentioned, you haven't paid attention to the size of the hidden coefficients. If they are all comparably sized, then your calculation is correct. But if they're not -- e.g. if the hidden coefficient on the $i$-th term is $\mathcal{O}(2^i)$, then the summation would work out to be $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting this equation without big O notation:
$$\begin{align}
T(1)&=e \\
T(n)&=2T(\frac n2)+cn+d
\end{align}
$$
where $c$, $d$, $e$ are constant.

Substituting a couple times:
$$\begin{align}
T(n)&=2T\left(\frac n2\right)+cn+d \\
&=2\left(2T\left(\frac n{2^2}\right)+c\frac n2+d\right)+cn+d \\
&=2\left(2\left(2T\left(\frac n{2^3}\right)+c\frac n{2^2}+d\right)+c\frac n2+d\right)+cn+d \\
&=2^3T\left(\frac n{2^3}\right)+\frac{2^2}{2^2}cn+\frac 22cn+cn+2^2d+2d+d \\
&=2^iT\left(\frac n{2^i}\right)+icn+\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}2^kd \\
&=2^iT\left(\frac n{2^i}\right)+icn+\frac{2^i-1}{2-1}d \\
&=ne+(\log_2n)cn+(n-1)d
\end{align}
$$
Because $c$, $d$, $e$ are constant this is ${\cal O}(n\log n)$.